# Responsive design doesn't display correctly on iphone

Tags: iphone, responsive-design

This is my first responsive site. It was originally a regular site but the client now wants it to fit on iphones, ipads, etc.

I created all of the media queries and checked them using FF web dev toolbar's View Responsive Layouts. Everything looks good so I uploaded it to a test server and it just shows the regular site view very small.

There must be something small I'm missing but I can't figure it out.

http://lovetro.com/dwi-rochester/

Answer (score 3):

You're missing the viewport `<meta>` tag, which tells the iPhone what size it should display the page at. Thus, it think it's gotten a desktop site at roughly 960px and displays it as such.

Add to your `<head>`:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Answer (score 2):

Add this in your head:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

Comment: That works @drip, but it would also stop the user from zooming. That may or may not be what Rev. Samuel was looking for, but it would be better to point out what they do. (Still a correct answer though :])